# Removing Anonymous Author in RANLP Submission

Tags: formatting, templates, paper, hidden

I am using the RANLP template for paper submission and trying to type my name instead of the line "Anonymous RANLP 2021 submission". Although I added my name in the .tex main file, my name doesn't show up and the anonymous line is still there. I tried to look at the .sty file and I doubt this command could be the reason

`\newcommand\outauthor{

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
\ifaclfinal 
     \bf\@author
\else 
    % Avoiding common accidental de-anymization issue. --MM
    \bf Anonymous RANLP 2021 submission
\fi
\end{tabular}} `
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I am not familiar with that template. But looking at the code you posted, it appears that the boolean `\faclfinal` must be true, for your purpose. So, what do you need to do, the make that true? Do you need a `[final]` document class option, or something like that?

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with editing sty files in LaTeX, so I don't know what to do exactly. All I need is to remove the line that blocks my name, affiliation and email from appearance in the top of the page. If you like, you can take a look at the template from its official website here: https://ranlp.org/ranlp2021/submissions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you need to edit any *sty file. I just looked at the template code (from your link). It looks like you can set the boolean, after you load the template (not before). Put this command in document preamble, immediately after loading the template files:

```
\aclfinalcopy
```

Aside: I do something similar for my own, custom document class. It prevents draft copies from accidentally being submitted (because the title and author are wrong, in draft mode).

Comment: Great!
Thanks so much. It works perfect.